# Entity Framework 6 - How do you add an entity with foreign key IdentityRole

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have a code first model with a mapping table so that I can map MenuItem to an IdentityRole, enabling the production of a menu based on the logged in users role assignment.

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class MenuRoleMap
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual MenuItem MenuItem { get; set; }
    public virtual IdentityRole Role { get; set; }
}
```

The IdentityRole and rest of Identity is auto wired via IdentityDbContext which I've inherited through my ApplicationDbContext like this, then the context should be consistent.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
```

All of the tables look right, they have the expected columns and foreign keys, here is the MenuRoleMap table

[image: table MenuRoleMap]

I have an valid existing instance of MenuItem and IdentityRole which I use to try and add a new entity item to this table

```
foreach (IdentityRole role in selectedRoles)
{
    MenuRoleMap mrm = new MenuRoleMap();
                mrm.MenuItem = menuItem;
                mrm.Role = role;
                db.MenuRoleMaps.Add(mrm);
}
db.SaveChanges();  ///  <<<=== HERE ERROR BECAUSE THE role IS ALREADY IN DB
```

Which throws this error

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
Role: Role SystemsAdministrator already exists.
```

Which of course, it does exist, I know that, it's already in the database.  Surely the EF should not be trying to add a new entity item for the foreign key entity if it already exists?

It doesn't do it for the MenuItem, only the IdentityRole.

I thought the problem was proxy creation since the IdentityRole was a proxy object, so I turned that off

```
this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

but I still get the same error.

My question is, how do you add an entity where the foreign key is an IdentityRole?

Thank you stackers.

---

ANSWER TO MY OWN QUESTION

After assistance from those below I discovered while investigating the various solutions that the problem wasn't one of context per se but the validity of an object.  The object looked right, what I hadn't realised is that it wasn't the object from the context, it was a facsimile.  By trying to add this facsimile to the model, the context quite rightly says it already exists, you can't add it again.  By trying to override the state of the item I created a different kind of error.

The resolution was simply to reload the object from the context and then add that to the parent item like so

```
foreach (IdentityRole role in selectedRoles)
{
    // Here I'm getting the role from the context using the ID I have from the facsimile
    IdentityRole roleToUse = db.Roles.Where(x => x.Id == role.Id).FirstOrDefault();
    // carry on as normal
    MenuRoleMap mrm = new MenuRoleMap();
    mrm.MenuItem = menuItem;
    mrm.Role = roleToUse;  // note I'm using the retrieved 'roleToUse'
    db.MenuRoleMaps.Add(mrm);
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

Hey presto it all works.

Comment: The selected roles are from the context like this --
ApplicationDbContext db = ApplicationDbContext.Create();
List<IdentityRole> selectedRoles = db.Roles.ToList();

Comment: The 'role' says db.Entry(role).State = Detached where as I can see that the 'menuItem' within the same context says State = Unchanged (which is true) I would expect both items to be unchanged.

Comment: Sorry I see I've made reference to the different contexts but actually they are one and the same as ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>.  This is an MVC project where in this instance the controller is passing the context to the method which retrieves the roles, in which case, I believe the context is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've retrieved the entity from another context and then assigned it to an entity which is then added to a different context.  It would then try to insert the Role entity too.

Are you returning the Role from another method where the lifetime of the context is scoped to that method?

You may find the following link useful in regards to updating the state of objects:
[Entity states and SaveChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj592676.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I've tried manually setting the Entity State to 'Added' but I get the same error.  What ever way I approach this, it always tries to create the EntityRole, it looks to me as if there is something under the hood that I can't see or, I'm using the EntityRole in the wrong way and you can't directly access them for some reason.

Comment: You would want to set the state as: `db.Entry(role).State = EntityState.Unchanged` instead of Added to prevent the insertion. By default, the EF doesn't know what is a new object or is an existing object unless you explicitly tell it, but you only need todo this for objects retrieved from another context to the one you're working on.  The context itself tracks the changes.  If you run `db.ChangeTracker.Entries()` whilst debugging prior to `SaveChanges` you can see the changes the context will make to the DB.

Comment: Further to my earlier answer accept, I now have to reveal my stupidity of assuming the object I have which looks like a 'role' is actually 'the role' and of course it isn't.  Therefore while the context is the same, the object was not same.  Simply resolved by retrieving the 'role' object again using the ID that I already have. Problem solved, thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you use `db.Set<MyEntity>.Add` you will mark all entities that are attached to the entity that is added as being added too.  You have to explicitly mark them as being unchanged:

```
foreach (IdentityRole role in selectedRoles)
{
    MenuRoleMap mrm = new MenuRoleMap();
                mrm.MenuItem = menuItem;
                mrm.Role = role;
                db.MenuRoleMaps.Add(mrm);
                db.Entry(role).State=EntityState.Unchanged;
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: You can do that of course, but you will run into problems when saving changes.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is you can't or at least should not.

Authentication (Roles), and Business (Menu) are different concerns of the application.

For me you have to bring in the ApplicationDb, the part of IdentityDb that you need and organize the synchronisation.

To illustrate my saying: Imaging you use Google or LiveID as authentification provider: can you imagine navigation properties from you ApplicationDd to Google or Microsoft Dbs ?

Clearly not.

So create a AppRole replicating the Role of the authentication database and use this table from your application database to build your menus.

In **pseudo code** this looks like:

```
List<Int32> l = IdentityContext.GetRolesForUser(currentUserId);
foreach (AppRole role in AppContext.Roles.Where(r => l.Contains(r.Id)))
{
    MenuRoleMap mrm = new MenuRoleMap();
            mrm.MenuItem = menuItem;
            mrm.Role = role;
            appContext.MenuRoleMaps.Add(mrm);
}
appContext.SaveChanges();
```

Another solution would be to use the same context for Application and Identity.

Inheritance of context seems fine, but I never tested it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the context is always the same and I've looked at the state of the object, setting the state of 'role' to Unchanged doesn't help, I get a different error, this time conflict of keys.  I'm accepting this as the answer on the basis that I accept the argument from @tschmit007 that the _Authentication (Roles), and Business (Menu) are different concerns of the application_